# Conditional Joins in one single query

Tags: sql, oracle11g

There are three tables with data as below:

TRADES:

[image]

GRD_TIME_ZONE:

[image]

PRI_TIME_ZONE:

[image]

I have to obtain time_zone value. For that I have two options:

Option 1:

```
SELECT trade_id, t.grd_exch_cd, time_zone_name
FROM trades t
JOIN grd_time_zone gtz ON t.grd_exch_cd = gtz.grd_exch_cd;
```

[image]

Option 2:

```
SELECT t.trade_id, t.grd_exch_cd, time_zone_name
FROM trades t
JOIN pri_time_zone ptz ON t.trade_id = ptz.trade_id;
```

[image]

If you notice, I don't get time_zone values for all the 3 trades.

My requirement is to combine both the above queries into a single query using the following logic:

- If grd_exch_cd in trades table is mapped to one and only one time_zone in grd_time_zone table, then get the value from there.
- If grd_exch_cd in trades table is NULL, get time_zone value from pri_time_zone table.
- If grd_exch_cd in trades table is mapped to more than 1 time_zone in grd_time_zone table, then get time_zone value from pri_time_zone table.

```
SELECT trade_id, t.grd_exch_cd, time_zone_name
FROM trades t
-- if grd_exch_cd is mapped to one time_zone in grd_time_zone
JOIN grd_time_zone gtz ON t.grd_exch_cd = gtz.grd_exch_cd
-- else if grd_exch_cd is NULL or mapped to more than one time_zone in grd_time_zone
JOIN pri_time_zone ptz ON t.trade_id = ptz.trade_id;
```

Can someone please help in devising such a query which performs conditional join.

Answer (score 1):

My inclination would be to use outer joins in an aggregate query to accomplish this:

```
SELECT t.trade_id, 
       t.grd_exch_cd, 
       CASE Count(DISTINCT gtz.time_zone_name) 
         WHEN 1 THEN Max(gtz.time_zone_name) 
         ELSE Max(ptz.time_zone_name) 
       END 
FROM   trades t 
       left join grd_time_zone gtz 
              ON t.grd_exch_cd = gtz.grd_exch_cd 
       left join pri_time_zone ptz 
              ON t.trade_id = ptz.trade_id 
GROUP  BY t.trade_id, 
          t.grd_exch_cd
```

- We're using `MAX` to consolidate many values. If there's more than one `gtz.time_zone_name`, then we won't use that value anyway, so it doesn't matter which one we pick.
- `gtz.time_zone_name` will return zero if there is no corresponding `grd_time_zone` entry, so there is no need to explictly check for `null`.
- `left join` (aka an outer join) is how you say "give me everything from `trades`, but only the matching records from `grd_time_zone`" in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a query which first joins trades and pri_time_zone table and then union the result with another query which takes all time zones which are exactly matched. Just an idea:

```
SELECT T.TRADEID ,
       T.GRD_EXCH_CD ,
       PTZ.TIME_ZONE_NAME
FROM   TRADES T
       INNER JOIN PRI_TIME_ZONE PTZ
         ON T.TRADEID = PTZ.TRADEID
UNION
SELECT T.TRADEID, 
       GTZ.GRD_EXCH_CD, 
       GTZ.TIME_ZONE_NAME
FROM   TRADES T  
       JOIN GRD_TIME_ZONE GTZ
          ON T.GRD_EXCH_CD = GTZ.GRD_EXCH_CD
WHERE   T.TRADEID in 
                       (SELECT    T.TRADEID
                        FROM      TRADES T  
                                  JOIN GRD_TIME_ZONE GTZ
                                    ON T.GRD_EXCH_CD = GTZ.GRD_EXCH_CD
                        GROUP BY T.TRADEID
                        HAVING COUNT(*) =1)
```